# Principal flow CSS

Tags: html, css

In order of creating my website, I'm getting following warning in Firefox browser:

> When rendering the  element, the used values of CSS properties “writing-mode”, “direction”, and “text-orientation” on the  element are taken from the computed values of the  element, not from the  element’s own values. Consider setting these properties on the :root CSS pseudo-class. For more information see “The Principal Writing Mode” in https://www.w3.org/TR/css-writing-modes-3/#principal-flow

I don't know what's wrong with it and what should I do.

Is there anyone who can figure this out?

I have already tried

```css
:root{
    direction:initial;
    text-orientation:initial;
    writing-mode:initial;
}
```

---

```css
body,html,:root{
    direction:initial;
    text-orientation:initial;
    writing-mode:initial;
}
```

But still the warning is there. I'm using material UI.

Comment: Could you please give us an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that produces the warning message?

Comment: After the :root, add *, *::before, *::after{direction:inherit; text-orientation:inherit; writing-mode:inherit.

Comment: I have found the solution. I used `dir="rtl"` in `<body>` tag. I removed it and the warning is gone now!